# Function that will generate a set of points satisfying certain geometric conditions

Tags: functions, geometry

I need to write function, which given some `n > 10` and a vector `vec{a}` in the xy-plane, that generates `n` random points in `{-n, n} x {-n, n}`. For each of those points I need to find the orthogonal projection the point on the line through `{1, 2}` and the vector a.

Does any of this makes sense?

```
f[n_, vec {a} _] := 
  Module[{k = n}, 
    T = RandomReal[{-n, n}, {n, 2}];
    For[i = 1, i <= k,  
      T' = 
        {
          Solve[
            {y - 2 - (vec {a}[[2]]/vec {a}[[1]])*(x - 1) == 0,  
             y - T[[i]][[2]] + (vec {a}[[1]]/vec {a}[[2]])*(x - T[[i]][[1]]) == 0}, 
             {x, y} ]
        };
        i++]]
```

Comment: `vec {a}` is `vec` multiplied by a length 1 list containing `a`. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

This may be more a query than an answer, but are you looking for something like this?

```
projections[n_Integer /; n > 10, aPt : {_, _}] :=
  Module[{pt2, rndPts, line, projPts},
    pt2 = {1, 2};
    rndPts = RandomReal[{-n, n}, {n, 2}];
    line = InfiniteLine[{aPt, pt2}];
    projPts = RegionNearest[line, #] & /@ rndPts;
    Print @ 
      Graphics[
        {line,
         {Dashed, MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {rndPts, projPts}]},
         {AbsolutePointSize[5], 
            Darker[Green, .25], Point[rndPts], Red, Point[projPts]}},
        Frame -> True];
    projPts]

SeedRandom[1]; projections[11, {5, -8}]
```

[image: plot]

> ```
> {{5.46269, -9.15672}, {4.79868, -7.49669}, {4.06128, -5.65321}, {3.71944, -4.7986}, 
>  {-0.284679, 5.2117}, {-1.2091, 7.52274}, {3.23317, -3.58293}, {0.53294, 3.16765}, 
>  {2.25006, -1.12516}, {3.13798, -3.34494}, {4.61176, -7.02941}}
> ```

- The line shown is the line defined by the two points `{1, 2}` and `{5, 8}`, the first being fixed and the second be given by the second argument of the function `projections`.
- The green points are the `n` selected random points. I have taken `n = 11` in the example.
- The red points are orthogonal projections of the green points onto the line. Their coordinates are returned by the function.

Does this example capture the situation you are asking about? If it doesn't, please edit your question (do not use the commenting facility) to explain how what you want differs from this.